# My login page is not working, if statement keeps activating nonetheless

Tags: php, mysql, html

```
<div class = "login">
<?php

    $lusername=$_POST['lusername'];
    $lpassword=$_POST['lpassword'];

    $mysql = new mysqli("localhost", "root", null, "webdb");

    $stmt = $mysql ->prepare("select username, password from webdb.user where username=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $lusername);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($u, $p);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
    $mysql->close();

    if($lusername == $u && $lpassword == $p) {
        echo "the log in is successful";
    }
    else {
        echo "<b><font color='red'>Login unsuccessful. Please go back and try again </font></b>";
    }
?>

<form action="sign in.php" method="post">

    <div class = "details">
  <br>
  &nbsp<input type="text" name="lusername" placeholder="Username" required>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="password" name="lpassword" placeholder ="Password" required>

</div>
<div class = "enter">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter">
</div>
```

I've been working on my login page for a day but I cannot seem to find the error in my codes. Currently, when I click on login, it automatically activates the if statement "the log in is successful" without even having to key in the username and password.

Comment: I hope this isn't live code. Your passwords aren't secure. You should look into `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`

Comment: Unsure if this makes any odds but `$mysql ->prepare` should be `$mysql->prepare` (no space between)

Comment: I think it's coming back true because both variables are null so therefore equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class = "login">
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $lusername=$_POST['lusername'];
    $lpassword=$_POST['lpassword'];

    $mysql = new mysqli("localhost", "root",'', "webdb");

    $stmt = $mysql ->prepare("select username, password from webdb.user where username=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $lusername);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($u, $p);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
    $mysql->close();

    if($lusername == $u && $lpassword == $p) {
        echo "the log in is successful";
    }
    else {
        echo "<b><font color='red'>Login unsuccessful. Please go back and try again </font></b>";
    }
}
?>

<form action="sign in.php" method="post">

    <div class = "details">
  <br>
  &nbsp<input type="text" name="lusername" placeholder="Username" required>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="password" name="lpassword" placeholder ="Password" required>

</div>
<div class = "enter">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter">
</div>
```

try this as you are first checking the `GET` request, and it will always give the login successful, for that you need to check whether the `submit` button has been pressed, and remove the `null` from the `database password` as for `blank password` you keep `''` and not `null`

Comment: Not to darken your answer but shouldn't there be some explanation of your changes / fixes for others to reference off of?

Comment: hey bro, sorry for that, thanks for making me remember what an asshole i am :)

Comment: Haha, I wouldn't suggest that about anybody here who's trying to help. Just a little insight as your answers now something others can use if they too are stuck with a similar problem. With no reasoning / info behind the changes doesn't help someone with little knowledge of coding or bug fixing ;)

Comment: yeah you should point it because the answers are for future users, and without any context its hard to understand where the fault was, thanks again bro :)

Answer (score 2):

**1st :** use `isset` to avoid `undefined index` error on page load for the first time .

```
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ //all you php code here }
```

**2nd :** Don't save the password as plain text in database .Try to use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`

**3rd :** On the error debugging mode. On top of page add these two lines

`ini_set('display_errors','On');  ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);`

Answer (score 0):

1) **Do no store password as a plain text** use password_hash() to store it correclty. And use password_verify() to verify if the password is correct. Link: http://www.phptherightway.com/#password_hashing. I hope it is not a live app.

2)Use this to escape : htmlentities( $slusername, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, $encoding = 'UTF-8' )

--------------------SOLUTION-------------------------------------------

The problem is that you don't submit the data with if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" ) and sign in.php should be sign_in.php. There is a space. AND REMOVE THE NULL on your mysqli database put ''.

2)In your your sign_in.php. Use this code.

```
<?php
/* Database connection start */
   $servername = "localhost";
   $username = "root";
   $password = "";

   try {
       $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=webdb", $username, $password);
       // set the PDO error mode to exception
       $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
       }
   catch(PDOException $e)
      {
       echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
      }

      /*if submission button */
   if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" ) {

       /*There is no protection here*/
       /*use $lusername=$htmlentities( $slusername, ENT_QUOTES | 
       ENT_HTML5, $encoding = 'UTF-8' );*/

       $lusername=$_POST['lusername'];
       $lpassword=$_POST['lpassword'];

       /*Query*/
       $query = 'SELECT password, username FROM user WHERE username 
       =:username';
       $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
       $stmt -> bindParam(':username', $lusername);
       $stmt->execute();
       $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
       $stmt->execute();
       $stmt->CloseCursor();

       /*Arranging query*/
       function returnArray( $rows, $string )
       {
            foreach( $rows as $row )
            {
                return $row[ $string ];
             }
        }

        /*Verification of the user*/
        if( returnArray( $rows, 'password') == $lpassword)
          {
              echo "the log in is successful";
          }
        else
          {
              echo "<b><font color='red'>Login unsuccessful. Please 
              go back and try again </font></b>";
           }
     }
 ?>
```

In your login.php

```
<div class = "login">
    <form action="sign_in.php" method="post">
        <div class = "details">
            <br>
             &nbsp<input type="text" name="lusername" 
             placeholder="Username" required>
             <br>
             <br>
             <br>
             <input type="password" name="lpassword" placeholder 
             ="Password" required>
         </div>
         <div class = "enter">
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter">
         </div>
    </form>
</div>
```